# C++ global constant in RAM not ROM

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, embedded

Good day,

I noticed that when I have the following code:

```
int foo(const int arg){
    return arg*10;
}

const int MY_VAR = foo(10);

main(){

    while(true){

    }
}
```

Then the MY_VAR is placed in the RW data section (RAM). Honestly I expected a compiler error. I'm using GNU ARM 6.2 2016q4 release.

If I make MY_VAR constexpr, then I get a compiler error. If I make foo constexpr then, as expected, MY_VAR is placed into the .text section (i.e. in ROM).

As constexpr variables can not be used as extern, I will have to use const variables for truly global constants.

What ways are there that I can automatically (i.e. compiler warning or error) detect that a constant is not being assigned to ROM?

I do want to use the ability to initialise some of the const globals with functions. Though I would want to catch the cases where the function is not constexpr automatically.

Comment: the constant `MY_VAR` is a global. it is allocated in RAM

Comment: BTW did you try a [`section` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)? You might want to [edit] your question and clarify whether you want help with using it; or maybe you want an alternative solution.

Comment: ROM is not the same as a read-only section of RAM.

Comment: Constant created with the keyword `const` are created in RAM, the compiler only ensures that there is no write access directly to it. But you're still able to "cast away" the const key word by accessing it through a pointer which is casted to a pointer without const. So `const` is just a check for the compiler during compile time. You will be still able to change it during runtime.

Comment: Changing `const` variables by casting away `const` invokes undefined behavior (at least in C++; I don't know about C). Sometimes it will work; some other times it will lead to a crash (segmentation violation - writing to read-only memory). It seems that OP wants the latter behavior (actually, even more specific behavior - that the variable be placed into the `.text` section).

Comment: @anatolyg It is undefined behavior in C as well.

Comment: If you compile this as standard C, you will indeed get a compiler error. Hardened veterans always take some time before program release to read through the map file and see if anything fishy ended up inside RAM.

Comment: Shouldn't this work fine with `constexpr`?

Comment: OP specified that he wants to declare the variable `extern` in some other source file, so no, it doesn't work with `constexpr`.

Comment: @gmug: That is wrong. The language does not require this and the compiler (resp. the linker) will place them in ROM if possible. It is just not posible because of the function call.

Comment: @Lundin Looking at the MAP is how I realised it was in the RAM. I was hoping for a C like compile error. In C, you almost only have to check the variable declaration. In C++ it seems you need to check that and the initialiser function (too make sure the latter is constexpr). I suppose one could somehow write a script to check for consts that are not in ROM.

Comment: @gmug In embedded devices consts are typically stored in ROM. You physically can't change them. They really are constants. In proper OS environments, yes, they are typically loaded into RAM and you can change them.

Comment: @Flip: yes of course you're right, my fingers were faster than my brain ;-)

Comment: @Flip So, did you try a `section` attribute?

Comment: @anatolyg section won't help in this instance. I'll only get a mem fault when it tries to write the runtime calculated value to flash on start up. This is a quirk of C++ that I was unaware of (used to C99). If I want to police it automatically, I'll probably have to create a script of some sort to run through the map.

Answer (score 3):

Your constant variable `MY_VAR` is initialized with the result of a function call - This means it cannot be initialized at compile time and thus cannot be put in ROM. The initialisation is done during the startup of your application at run-time.

There is no way to generate a warning if such placements are done - After all, you told the compiler to do so.

You can, however, have the linker generate a link map and manually check whether all your constants have actually ended up in the proper segments.

Comment: Just to point out, if it is initialised with a constexpr function, this is not a problem.

Comment: @Flip That is correct - A `constexpr` function, however, cannot have a global scope result.